# SVG/Raphael: All paths through a given point?

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm using RaphaelJS to implement some event-heavy SVG.  I have a set of paths on a canvas, and a point.  How can I get all the paths that cross that point?  Relatively new at this, but I assumed this would be trivial and I can't find anything about it.

If it helps, the specific implementation is trying to detect on the mousedown event if I've clicked on a path so I can rotate it around another point onmousemove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a portable (supporting both the SVG and VML backends of raphael) way to do this without implementing the math yourself. However, for browsers that support SVG, the SVG spec includes built-in support for exactly what you are requesting:

[http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#_*svg*_SVGSVGElement__getIntersectionList](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__getIntersectionList)

Answer (score 0):

Vector is math. Find the equations of the lines and see if the point fulfill the equation.